# Reading text file with bufferedReader adds a whitespace, android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have this method to get an arrayList from a text file:

```
private ArrayList<String[]> tempList(){
        String temp = null;
        ArrayList<String[]> tempList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        try {
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(getFilename())));
            while ((temp = bReader.readLine()) !=null){
            String[] value = temp.split(",");
                tempList.add(value);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tempList;
    }
```

The file has just letters separated by comma with no space or empty lines. The problem is that somehow the first letter of the list has a whitespace in front of it. All other letters are fine.

here is the txt file which contains a local alphabet:

```
Α,Β,Γ
Δ,Ε,Ζ
Η,Θ,Ι
Κ,Λ,Μ
Ν,Ξ,Ο
Π,Ρ,Σ
Τ,Υ,Φ
Χ,Ψ,Ω
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: I have try your code and is working perfectly and have you debug code then you know updated value of templList.

Comment: Make use of trim() function of String class if you have any leading or trailing spaces in the string..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *could* be a zero-width space, a BOM, `'\uFEFF'` normally used as first char (by NotePad under Windows) to mark Unicode files as such. So Windows can distringuish between UTF-8 and normal local ANSI.

If during editing the first line was copied, and afterwards a conversion of character encoding took place, that would be the explanation.

```
temp = temp.replace("\uFEFF", "");
```

In general this removal of BOM is a good idea.

Comment: @Joop thank you so much! After trying to remove every kind of whitespace I could think of, and feeling frustrated, I was finally able to resolve my issue!

Answer (score 1):

Just do a little change in your code as suggested from @user3505725 :

```
String[] value = temp.trim().split(",");
```

Hope this will help.