# Android ArrayList without first value

Tags: java, android, random, arraylist

I have problem with `ArrayList`. I have the question files structure like:

Y aaaaaa.

Y bbbbbb.

N ccccccc.

N ddddddd.

and I want to put into textview3 the first letter like Y or N

```
public void value (){

        Scanner answerScanner = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.answer));
         Scanner questionScanner = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.question));

        ArrayList<String> answerList = new ArrayList<String>();
          ArrayList<String> questionList = new ArrayList<String>();

           try {
               while (answerScanner.hasNextLine() ) {
                   answerList.add(answerScanner.nextLine());  
                   questionList.add(questionScanner.nextLine()); 
               }
           } finally {
               answerScanner.close();  
               questionScanner.close();
           }  

           int nextInt = random.nextInt(questionList.size());

           String answerString = answerList.get(nextInt);
           String questionString = questionList.get(nextInt);

           yourAnswerString = answerString.substring(0);
           yourQuestionString = questionString.substring(2);
           shortform = questionString.substring(0,1);


           TextView textGenerateNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
           TextView textGenerateNumber2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
           TextView textGenerateNumber3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
           textGenerateNumber.setText(yourQuestionString);
           textGenerateNumber2.setText(yourAnswerString);
           textGenerateNumber3.setText(shortform);
       }
```

then I add:

```
shortform = questionString.substring(0,1);
TextView textGenerateNumber3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
textGenerateNumber3.setText(shortform);
```

I get good answers I all cases without first .... when radom get first line from text file I get empty value ( my textView3 are empty).

Comment: Check with int nextInt = random.nextInt(questionList.size()-1);. That will work.

Comment: I still get empty textView3 :(

Comment: Use  shortform = questionString.charAt(0); and check. If this is not working you are getting empty string in previous line or you are modifying the text3 value again after calling value() method.

Comment: If you try with 'textGenerateNumber3.setText("hello");' do you see 'hello' appear?

Comment: Yes i see hello. I dont see only value from first line from text file :Y from ( Y aaaaaa.), I see Y from Y bbbbbb and N from N ccccccc etc.

Comment: I see a mistake in first line. Only first value after Y is shift by one space forward, when random get first i get: <space>aaaaaa. and when random get second i get bbbbbb, etc

Comment: I dont know why i get <space> only in first row in text file. Anyone know how I can fix it?

Comment: I found answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263629/reading-text-file-with-bufferedreader-adds-a-whitespace-android